# Table names in migrations while migrate to STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sti

Some time ago I've realized that we need STI instead of schema we used. So now I've started to migrate our app and face with several problems.
Let's imagine we had such schema (it's little bit more complicated, but that doesn't matter):

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Lion < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Horse < ActiveRecord::Base
 ..
end
```

So, after applying STI it obviously looks like this

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Lion < Animal
  ...
end

class Horse < Animal
 ..
end
```

But then I need to put all staff from `lions` and `horses` tables into `animals`.

So I wrote such a migration:

```
  def change
    Lion.find_each do |l|
      Animal.create(
        name: l.name,
        type: 'Lion'
        )
    end
  end
```

and it didn't work. 'Cause when doing `Lion.find_each` it already retrieves data from `Animals` with `Lion` type.
I found two ways of resolving this:

1) First write and run migration and then change code in models. But that won't work on staging, production or even on another developer's computer,  since first all code changes will be retrieved from repo and then all migrations will be ran...

2) In migration file instead of `Lion.find_each` I can write `Lion.find_by_sql("select * from lions").each` and that will do what I need, but it looks ugly.

Is there a way to implement this more elegant?

Comment: Within your migration you can monkey patch your model classes and set the table name to the old one and creste a dummy class witch points to the new table via self.table_name.

Comment: You can use [`#from`](http://http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method) to specify the table to use in the query. `Lion.select('l.*').from('Lions', :l)`. Not sure if it works with batches but its worth a try.

Comment: Also don't use a migration for operations like this that are intended to be run only once to fix bad data. Instead create a topical branch in your repository where you write a rake task to fix the problem. Push the topical branch to production - run the task to fix the records and then roll back to the last code deploy.

Comment: The reason you don't want to use a migration is that they are merely intended to alter the schema of the DB and do not handle long running tasks well - in a way that is repetable.